# Wordpress tables: Dynamic table from SQL database

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am currently trying to implement a (wordpress) website that shows a table which is dynamically filled from an SQL database based on user input. Let me give a little detail as to what I'm trying to achieve:

- I have a big database that contains a list of documents with details such as filer, date, link to document
- On my website, I want to show a table with pre-defined columns that is empty at the start
- when the user starts to type in values either in one of the pre-defined columns, or in a separate search box (whatever is easier to implement for now), the table should dynamically query the database and show the 10 best matches for that input.

I have no idea where to start, I've seen a couple of (paid) wordpress plugins to achieve this, but I wonder if that's something I could implement myself?

Thanks already for your help

Answer (score 1):

For an MVP I'd go with [Gravity Forms](https://www.gravityforms.com/) (for user input) + [Gravity View](https://gravityview.co/) (for displaying data) pair. It will do the job, 100%. After you see what's working and what's not, you might dive into custom development and code something that suits all your needs.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but this looks like a paid solution as well. Like I said I found a few plugins already that seem to be able to do the trick, like wpDataTables, but I was curious if it would be feasible to do myself..